# JQuery click on link not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, click

Ive the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    shortcut.add("Ctrl+Alt+N", function() {
        $("#btnSave").click();
    });
});
</script>
```

where btnSave is anchor element with ID btnSave, shortcut is from http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/ . If i change the line `$("#btnSave").click();` to `document.getElementById("btnSave").click()` - all works fine. The question is why jquery implementation is not working in my case?
**PS: made jsfiddle for my case: http://jsfiddle.net/0x49D1/WCmeU/**
Here is the guy with similar problem: http://forums.asp.net/t/1591818.aspx

Comment: Where and how do you bind the click event for `#btnSave`?

Comment: @VisioN, i want to simulate user's click on link. Actually this is part of asp.net code and click on the link runs inokes some server event. Still, see my added JSFIDDLE sample. And if the case is with click binding, why `document.getElementById("btnSave").click();` is working?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Instead of `$("#btnSave").click();` try with `$("#btnSave").trigger('click');`

You can also use `$("#btnSave")[0].click();` which is jquery equivalent to `document.getElementById("btnSave").click();`

**Update**:
It's not possible to simulate a user link click from javascript, for security reasons, all you can do is attach your own handler for `click` event and  redirect based on the `href` of the link, like so:

```
$("#btnSave").bind('click', function() {
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Comment: What you want to do is not possible, but you can kind of simulate it, see my update.

Comment: Then why `shortcut.add("Ctrl+Alt+N", function() {
    //$("#btnSave").click();
    document.getElementById("btnSave").click();
});​` works?..Think im missing something :( http://jsfiddle.net/0x49D1/WCmeU/13/

Comment: What is forbidden is simulate following the link adress, if the link had href="http://www.google.com" instead of href="javascript: alert('tada')" your code wouldn't follow to google.

Comment: see new update for a jquery equivalent for your javascript click code.

Comment: Works..But now if i click on link with mouse-it shows 'tada' twice. Anyway i needed an explanation about that behaviour and youve given it to me. Can you provide some links on documentation? Thank you.

Comment: @0x49D1 simply remove the javascript:... fomr the href to the click handler

Comment: @RuneFS, yes, but that is sample code..Actualy on my form that link runs some javascript(and does postback).

Comment: @0x49D1 yes and as wrote all you have to do is move that to your click handler

Comment: @0x49D1 What I said about forbidden following link address is true, but only for external links, because they will be violating same-origin policy, if the link href is some page in the same host/port/protocol as the origin page, then calling .click() will follow the link.  As documentation see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I don't think you answer the question of _why_ the jquery doesn't work which seemed to be the OP's original question and one I'd like an answer to as well.  But still +1 for suggesting `$("#btnSave")[0].click();` which solved my immediate problem.

Comment: Also to get it working can be used: `$("#btnSave").get(0).click();`

Answer (score 0):

try this

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript"> 
>       $(document).ready(function(){
>          shortcut.add("Ctrl+Alt+N", function() {
>             $("#btnSave").live('click',function(){
>            // do stuff here
>             });
>          }); 
>       }); </script>
> ```